# Nothing is being detected in Yolov3 Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing

this should recognize the cars in the image and draw the squares around them, I don't know why it's not working... could someone give me some hints?

code and image with no detection:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t24cw.jpg)

```
import os
from cv2 import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox


im =cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\gmobi\\PycharmProjects\\ComputerVisionStudent\\imagens\\carros.jpeg")
bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(im)
output_image = draw_bbox(im, bbox, label, conf)
plt.imshow(output_image)
plt.show()
print('Number of cars in the image is ' + str(label.count('car')))
```

Installed packages:

```
Keras: 2.2.5

cvlib: 0.2.2

opencv-python: 4.1.1.26

tensorflow: 1.14.0

matplotlib: 3.1.1
```

source code from git: 
https://github.com/sabiipoks/blog-posts/blob/master/Count_Number_of_Cars_in_Less_Than_10_Lines_of_Code_Using_Python.ipynb

my settings:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUFuH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network that cvlib is using for the object detection is YoloV3. This network expects to get an image in the RGB color space and not BGR color space which is what opencv cv2.imread is returning.

So i think you should convert the color space of the image from BGR to RGB.

```
im =cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\gmobi\\PycharmProjects\\ComputerVisionStudent\\imagens\\carros.jpeg")

im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Another reason could be the size of the object in your image. The input size to Yolo is around 411x411 pixels so your image will be resized before it will be inserted to network and after the resize the objects will look to small. Try to crop the image and then insert it.

Im = im[:412,:412,:]

Comment: `im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

I just added it to the code but it didn't work, the only difference is that there is color now.